# Manage tow Signals in two different apps in Django

Tags: python, django, signals

i have two Django applications, **blogApp** and **accounts**, when i created a signal file for blogapp that can slugify title after saving the model into database, this works perfectly.
But when i added the second signal file to accounts that can create profile to the user when he finished his registration, it shows me this error:
[image: Post matching query does not exist.], and when i check the admin section, i can see the profile has been successfully created.

PostModel in blogApp application:
[image: PostModel in blogApp application]

Signals in blogApp application:
[image: Signals in blogApp application]

ProfileModel in accoounts application:
[image: Profile Model in accounts app]

Signals in accounts application:
[image: Signals in accounts app]

So, how can i create the user profile without indexing to Post signals.
Because what i'm thinking is the two signals of two apps is activating after the user press register.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, your problem is with the sender you have set.
You want to make a specific action about a Post instance,but you set User as sender ?
So in your receive function, you try to get a Post instance with as id the id of the user provided as isntance.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Post)
def slugify_title_model_field(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        post_to_slugify = Post.objects.get(id=instance.id)
        post_to_slugify.title = slugify(post_to_slugify.title)
        post_to_slugify.slug = slugify(post_to_slugify.title)
        post_to_slugify.save()
```

Of course, you have to remove the `post_save.connect...` write after this code.

But for this case, I advise you to overload the save function of your model, it is there for that, and it would be much more logical to put this function in a model because it directly concerns the instance being saved. I use signals to deal with cases external to the model itself in general.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you, Lucas, it works perfectly, I didn't notice the User instead of Post.

for your suggestion:
Do you mean in save method, i should slugify the title or add the signal method to the model itself (Post model)?

Comment: I think you do not need a signal for making your slugify action. just override save method and set your code inside it. i will edit my post for example

Comment: Yeah, i did the same you mentioned, but this is just to test how two signals in different apps works, Thanks Lucas again, appreciated)